# browse files button doesn't work when i click

Tags: magento-1.9, product, php, product-images, product-edit

I am having a problem with the `browse files` button not working when clicked.  I don't know why, adobe flash plugin is working fine, I am using magento 1.9

thank you

[image]

Comment: check js error in console.

Comment: You can also check your logs (system.log, exception.log, ...) and your reports